# Swift 4.2 Error - Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Tags: swift

I have swift code like below. I get

> "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)"

error on

> static var shared

I do not understand the error or the reason for it.

```
class FooApi: SomeApi {

......

   static var shared: FooApi = {
      let c = URLSessionConfiguration.default
      c.httpAditionalHeaders = [......]
      return FooApi(configuration: c)
   }()
 ......
}
```

This is called in the following code:

```
class oneVC: UIViewController {
   private let fooapi: FooApi

   init(fooapi: FooApi = FooApi.shared) {
       self.fooapi = fooapi
   }

   //fooapi used in some functions
}
```

The code for SomeApi is like this:

```
class SomeApi {
    let configuration: URLSessionConfiguration
    ......

    init(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration, ....) {
       self.configuration = configuration
       ......
    }

    .........
}
```

If you need more information let me know.

Comment: Please post a minimal working example that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Need more info?

Comment: You can  initialise `fooapi` in `viewDidLoad` method.